# I want use ToolBar in my activity.java file and this toolbar has to be in layout.xml file which contains only ListView. How do I go about this?

Tags: android

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/categoriesLayout"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true">
```

I tried below xml. But I am getting an error stating "addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/categoriesLayout"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/categoriesLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You get that error, because of `ListView` is not a `ViewGroup`. It can not hold inside another view like `ViewGroup` - `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout` etc.

Comment: Thanks.. I just tried the above xml and it's working.

Comment: No problem, happy codding)